# Issue in removing html tags while using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup to scrape some data from a website but I am not able to remove html tags from the data while printing it. Referred code is:

```
import csv
import urllib2
import sys  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/smartphones.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
for anchor1 in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "listGrid-price"}):
    print anchor1
for anchor2 in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "gridPrice"}):
    print anchor2
for anchor3 in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "gridMultiDevicePrice"}):
    print anchor3
```

Output which I am getting using this, looks like this:

```
<div class="listGrid-price"> 
                                $99.99 
            </div>
<div class="listGrid-price"> 
                                $0.01 
            </div>
<div class="listGrid-price"> 
                                $0.01 
            </div>
```

I want only prices in output without having any html tags around it. Pardon me for my ignorance as I am new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the found tag. To only print the contained text, use the `.string` attribute:

```
print anchor1.string
```

The `.string` value is a [`NavigableString` instance](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring); to use it like a normal unicode object, convert it first. Then you could use `strip()` to remove the extra whitespace:

```
print unicode(anchor1.string).strip()
```

Adjusting this a little to allow for empty values:

```
for anchor1 in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "listGrid-price"}):
    if anchor1.string:
        print unicode(anchor1.string).strip()
```

which gives me:

```
$99.99
$0.99
$0.99
$299.99
$199.99
$49.99
$49.99
$99.99
$0.99
$99.99
$0.01
$0.01
$0.01
$0.01
$0.01
```

Comment: I tried to use anchor1.string earlier but it gave this error: "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"
After this I tried to change the recursion limit from 1000 to 1500 also but even then it didn't work

Comment: @user1915050: then make that the question, together with a traceback. In that case `anchor1` is not what you think it is, probably.

Comment: @user1915050: I just tried your code with `anchor1.string` and it works as expected